# What's the proper way to run a south schemamigration in a Django package?

Tags: django, django-south

I'm working with a third-party Django package, and I'm not sure how to create a schemamigration.  What's the equivalent of:

`./manage.py schemamigration <app_name>` when I don't have a `./manage.py`?

Comment: If your third-party uses buildout, then you'll not have `manage.py`. Instead of `manage.py` buildout creates executable files in ./bin directory. Look for the one of them.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't think we can create South migrations without build a real django site(btw, you also need the django site for testing). Just treat your package like other django packages, and run `schemamigration <your_app_name>` to create migrations for it.

You only need to let django store migrations under your package's migrations directory instead of 'env/lib/pythonXX/site-packages/' You need to install your app with pip's [editable](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/logic.html#editable-installs)” mode.

```
pip install -e local_path/to/your_package
```